# Drupal 7 - URL rewriting with hook_url_*_alter() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: url-rewriting, drupal-7, url-routing

Here's my situation: I have a bunch of HTML pages in sites/default/files/pdf. I want to serve them as is so I have links to them in my Drupal site. However, one of the requirements is that all the URLs of these HTML pages must not contain any extensions. In addition, I want it to act in such a way that when users go to example.com/sites/default/files/pdf/somehtmlfile, the URL will show as example.com/pdf/somehtmlfile and also when users visit example.com/pdf/somehtmlfile, example.com/sites/default/files/pdf/somehtmlfile will be served instead.

From my independent research, it seems that I should be using hook_url_inbound_alter() and hook_url_outbound_alter(). However, I seem to be doing something wrong because the URL does not change at all.

Below is my code. I created a module called html_extension_remover (not very imaginative name, I know). I have successfully activated the module and some debugging statements are run successfully, so I know that the module is running.

```
function html_extension_remover_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path){
    $pdf_regex = '|^sites/default/files/pdf(/.*)?|';
    $pdf_new_path = 'pdf';

    if (preg_match($pdf_regex,$path, $matches)) //rewrite all request to sites/default/files/pdf to pdf, looks nicer
        if (count($matches)==1)
            $path = $pdf_new_path;
        else
            $path = $pdf_new_path . $matches[1]; //append the rest of the URL, after the Regex match
    if (strpos($path, $pdf_new_path)!=FALSE) //URL contains pdf, means viewing converted PDFs in pdf dir
        if (strpos($path, '.htm')!=FALSE){ //if viewing .htm/.html file
            $path = substr(0, strpos); //strip extension from URL
        }

    $pdf_new_path = 'sites/default/files/pdf';
    $pdf_regex = '|^pdf(/.*)?|';

    if (preg_match($pdf_regex, $path, $matches)){
        if (count($matches)==1){
            $path = $pdf_new_path;
        }
        else{
            $path = $pdf_new_path.$matches[1].'.htm';
        }
    }
}

function html_extension_remover_url_inbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path){
    $pdf_new_path = 'sites/default/files/pdf';
    $pdf_regex = '|^pdf(/.*)?|';

    if (preg_match($pdf_regex, $path, $matches)){
        if (count($matches)==1){
            $path = $pdf_new_path;
        }
        else{
            $path = $pdf_new_path.$matches[1].'.htm';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution? I think I may have a simular problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176589/drupal-hook-url-inbound-alter-not-altering-my-url)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly URL rewriting is not what you need. Why? Because mapping an external URL to some internal URL / alias is not going to help you serve the file.

What you need is a way to have an external URL process a request and return the file in question. Luckily Drupal 7 makes this pretty easy to do.

1.) Define a menu mapping in hook_menu()

```
    function MODULE_menu() {
      $items = array();
      $items['pdf'] = array(
        'title' => 'Map PDF',
        'page callback' => 'MODULE_show_pdf',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'TBD',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
      return ($items);
    }
```

2.) Define your callback function

```
    function MODULE_show_pdf($somehtmlfile = '') {
      $stream_wrapper_uri = 'public://pdf/' . $somehtmlfile . '.pdf';
      $stream_wrapper = file_create_url($stream_wrapper_uri);
      $stream_headers = array(
        'Content-Type'      => file_get_mimetype($stream_wrapper_uri),
        'Content-Length'    => filesize($stream_wrapper_uri),
        'Pragma'            => 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control'     => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Expires'           => '0',
        'Accept-Ranges'     => 'bytes'
      );              
      file_transfer($stream_wrapper_uri, $stream_headers);
    }
```

Some things to note:

1. There is no need to explicitly define somehtmlfile param in the menu.  This allows you more flexibility in that you can simply define whatever params you would like this external URL to support simply by adjusting the params in the callback function.
2. When public stream wrapper dirs/files are sub-dir of: sites/default/files
3. It is assumed that although you have somehtmlfile in the URL that you really want to stream somehtmlfile.pdf (if you want to stream somehtmlfile.html then simply adjust the hard coded '.pdf' suffix)
4. file_transfer calls drupal_exit() as its last step which essentially ends request processing.
5. Make sure to flush your cache otherwise the above will not work as menu entries are cached and the external URL will fail to be found