# Drupal hook_url_inbound_alter not altering my url

Tags: php, url-rewriting, path, drupal-7

I have in my module named 'categorie' a implementation of:

```
function categorie_url_inbound_alter(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  if ($path == 'e') {
    $result = 'user';        
  }
}
```

I'm planning to do something a bit more advanced but I can't even seem to get the basic one working.

With this implementation I expect that if a user goes to mysite.com/e , he gets the user page. But I'm getting a 404.

In this topic:[Using module: url_alter and it's hook: hook_url_outbound_alter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587660/using-module-url-alter-and-its-hook-hook-url-outbound-alter) they also suggested you need to implement the hook_boot() with nothing in it. However I did implement this hook and this didn't change the behavior.

UPDATE:
I have the "Path" module installed from core and I declared some url aliases in the clean url section. (Maybe this gives a conflict?)

UPDATE2: cleaning the cache didn't do the trick either.

UPDATE3:
I also tries doing the url rewriting in the htaccess file. But when the url was rewritten it destroyed the theming. (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76475/drupal-does-rewrite-url-but-cant-load-css-themes/76493?noredirect=1#76493). So that's why I'm now trying to do it with the custom module.

Answer (score 0):

What cache did you clear ? It probably not sufficient 
to just clear the page cache. You can try a call to

drupal_lookup_path('wipe');

To clear the alias cache. This fixes many problems with the alias system. 
Other things to check are the alias database table to be sure that the alias are  being 
set in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, cause i'm also very new to drupal. But i think you need to implement hook_url_outbound_alter as well. Good luck. If i find a better answer i'll post it.

Cheers